# Two Words in one String with space

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to read inputs from file. I have line like this:
"Peter Brown Ashley Granger". There are two empty strings, name1 and name2. I want to get Peter Brown as name1 and Ashley Granger as name2. How can i do that ?

Comment: Offtopic: Your title reminded me of this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLE7zsJk4AI

Answer (score 0):

Read the two parts, then put them together.

Something along these lines:

```
std::string full_name;
std::string part1;
std::string part2;
if (stream >> part1 >> part2)
{
    full_name = part1 + " " + part2;
}
```

Comment: I got more than one lines in text file it is like:
"Peter Brown\tAshley Granger\n
 Michael\tHarry"
And sometimes there is no surname.

Comment: @vladimirbrosty from your comment it seems that the "full" names in your file are separeted by `'\t'` or `'\n'` while the single parts (of unknown number) only by `' '`. If I'm correct, please, edit your question to specify that.

Answer (score 0):

you can create three strings sFamilyName, sFirstName, sFullName so input the family name and first name using cin to stop at white space then concatenate the two in string three full name:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{   
    string sFamilyName, sFirstName, sFullName;
    ifstream in("data.txt");

    while(in >> sFamilyName >> sFirstName)
    {
        sFullName = sFamilyName + " " + sFirstName; 
        cout << sFullName << endl;
    }

    in.close();
    return 0;
}
```